# Checkbox label inside the checkbox or which button is activated?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, checkbox

I am searching for a solution to display something like this: [image]

I want to create a HTML form where you can select multiple days per week. Like Monday, Tuesday and so on. On the image you can see the german shortcuts for the days.

I could realize that with checkboxes but here I would face the problem that it wouldn't look like the picture.. I want to have the labels inside the checkboxes. It should exactly like on the picture... Do you have any ideas, how I could do that?

My other idea was to create buttons and simply change the color if they got clicked... But how would I know which button got clicked/is selected?

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Kind regards

Answer (score 4):

In a similar situation I've chosen to hide the checkbox and apply a style to an span. Take a look to this idea to check if it works for you. It doesn't require javascript.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

label :checked + span {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

label span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightgrey;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span>Mo</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Di</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Mi</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Do</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span>Fr</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Sa</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>So</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you Baleato. Just two more questions: 1. How can I transfer the checked "checkboxes" to the POST variable? (Because it doesn't appear). 2. Is that also possible with radio buttons?

Comment: For that second question you can use javascript. creating a list that appends the clicked day every time it happens, then send it via post by submit. every html item that represents each day must have it's own id, or you can use the same class for all too.

Comment: Hi, those input will be part of a form and by setting the attribute 'name' on them you'll be sending a true value on the POST. You can use those input normally, as if they were visible.

Comment: Just in case this can help clarifying how to intercept submit on a form https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp